# C# Write Data to a text File

Tags: c#, forms

I got a homework assignment here.  I've created a form with 4 text boxes for data entry, Account #, First Name, Last Name, Balance.  I have four buttons, Create File, Save data to file, clear, and exit.  Basically all the program does is create a text file, then I input my data into the text boxes, then I hit save data file which will write the data to the text file I have created.  Clear and Exit are already done, and I have the program working as far as creating the text file, now I just need someone to point me in the right direction on how to actually write the data I entered into the text file. Here is my code, Thanks in advance

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Chapter_17_Ex.Sample_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog file = new SaveFileDialog();
            file.FileName = "client.txt";
            file.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            file.ShowDialog();           

            StreamWriter filewrite = new StreamWriter(file.FileName);          



        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextWriter file = new TextWriter

        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtAccount.Clear();
            txtBalance.Clear();
            txtFirstName.Clear();
            txtLastName.Clear();
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `Write` and `WriteLine` method on [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx)? You should probably also use `StreamWriter` in an `using` block to make sure it is disposed of after use.

Comment: Since you already knew you were using the StreamWriter class, why didn't you just read the MSDN entry for it?

Comment: Thank you guys, with the other post and the MSDN I got it working, I will post my final code later but right now I cant because I dont have enough reputation points, also is it proper etiquette here to post your answer code or just do a thank you in comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with creating that StreamWriter instance. What you want to do now is use the `WriteLine()` method of that class. It's also a good idea to wrap that StreamWriter instance in a `using` block:

```
    private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SaveFileDialog file = new SaveFileDialog();
                file.FileName = "client.txt";
                file.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                file.ShowDialog();           

                using(StreamWriter filewrite = new StreamWriter(file.FileName))
                {
                     filewrite.WriteLine( String.Format("First Name is {0}", txtFirstName.Text)  );
                     //use Write() or WriteLine() again as needed.
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the file create you can use:

```
File.Create(file.FileName).Close(); // replace the StreamWriter code with this
```

For the simplest way to write into that file:

```
string line =  string.Join(",", txtAccount.Text, txtBalance.Text, txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text) + System.Environment.NewLine;
File.AppendAllText(file.FileName, line);
```

You also need to move the 'SaveFileDialog file' to be a class field, not a method local variable.

You didn't specify the output format. What I chose is CSV... but there's no "escaping" of the input, which needs to be done to prevent inputting commas from messing up the output. That part is up to you.

Note the use of `File.Create` and `File.AppendAllText` - these save you from having to put `using` around the actual I/O.